# getSupportFragmentManager on AccountAuthenticatorActivity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-support-library, accountmanager

How can I pass the getSupportFragmentManager() to external library in AccountAuthenticatorActivity?.

I need to put a custom dialog with android-styled-dialogs: https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs

Answer (score 17):

1. Take [AccountAuthenticatorActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorActivity.java) and put it in your project.
2. Instead of
   `AccountAuthenticatorActivity extends Activity` put `AccountAuthenticatorActivity extends FragmentActivity`.
3. Extend your class with your new `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` and use `getSupportFragmentManager()`.